# Recovering curve's equation from a given Kummer surface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Assuming I'm not in even characteristic and that the ground field is algebraically closed for simplicity, it is known that every genus 2 curve is associated to a Kummer surface in $\mathbb P^3$. If $\mathcal H : v^2=f(u)$ is a genus 2 Hyperelliptic curve in Weierstrass model, the Kummer surface $\mathcal K$ is then the quotient of the Jacobian variety of $\mathcal H$ by its canonical involution. With the standard degree 4 homogeneous equation for $\mathcal K$ in this case, $F_2(x,y,z)t^2+F_3(x,y,z)t+F4(x,y,z)=0$, we can find the curve inside the Kummer surface as the image of the conic $z^2=yt, x=0$. In this system of coordinates, the Weierstrass equation of the curve can be recovered by using the 6 nodes of $\mathcal K$ lying on this conic.

My questions are :
1) if I'm not in this appropriate coordinates system, i.e. I have a general Kummer surface as a 16 nodes surface in $\mathbb P^3$, is there a way to find an equation other than the Weierstrass one for $\mathcal H$ ? I mean here that I'm not interested in changing my coordinates system.

2) assuming I know the usual equation for $\mathcal K$ and thus the Weierstrass equation for $\mathcal H$ ; if I'm given an automorphism of $\mathbb P^3$, it transforms $\mathcal K$ to another Kummer surface $\mathcal K'$, which should be associated to another model of the curve, say $\mathcal H'$ (not being very rigourous here). Is there a way to build the transformation from $\mathcal H$ to $\mathcal H'$ using this context ?

I tried hard to answer the 2nd question lately, and it seems I hit a dead end, so that's why I'm looking for maybe new advices and ideas, or maybe sources to finish it myself, or even a negative answer could be fine.

I have read a lot of paper on the subject and found nothing interesting in modern treatments. I have a hard time understanding the book from Hudson, which is sad because it seems there are anwers in it.  I'm not really familiar with theta functions, I think I only have a basic understanding on how they work.